# Getting types from instance of a class in Swift

Tags: ios, class, variables, swift, instance

I have two files which I am working on for my SpriteKit game: SPSwipes.swift and GameScene.swift.

In my **SPSwipes.swift** file, inside an SPSwipes class, a *variable is triggered by an IBAction*.

```
class SPSwipes: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func fiveSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
        var no_of_swipes = 5
    }
}
```

In my **GameScene.swift file**, an if statement checks what *value has been assigned to my variable*, and creates an array thereof:

```
if no_of_swipes == 5 {
    var array = Array<UInt32>(count: 5, repeatedValue: 0)
    for i in 0 ..< 5 {
        array[i] = arc4random_uniform(100)
    }
}
```

I receive this **error message**:

[image]

To 'fix' the problem, I realised that *I needed to create an instance of my SPSwipes class*, so I added this to my **GameScene.swift** file:

```
var swipes = SPSwipes()
```

And then *I changed the if statement* to say:

```
if swipes.no_of_swipes == 5{
...
}
```

Then I received this **error**:

[image]

As far as I'm aware, I have created an instance of the class correctly, but there is evidently an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
@IBAction func fiveSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
    var no_of_swipes = 5
}
```

You have created a variable inside the function, therefore the variable doesn't exist outside of the function.

What you want is to have the variable live for as long as an object of the class lives, therefore you need to create the variable one level higher:

```
class SPSwipes: UIViewController {

var numberOfSwipes = 0

@IBAction func fiveSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
    numberOfSwipes = 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing, is it safe to do 'var numberOfSwipes = 5' inside the function, or should I leave out 'var'?

Comment: If you put var in the function, you will be creating a local variable that will be used in preference to the member variable.